# Distinct Combinations According to Last Date (mySQL/PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, distinct

I have a table with four columns:

```
id
date_added
variable1 (eg. a,b,c,d,e,f)
variable2 (eg. 1,2,3,4,5)
```

What I want is to echo out every distinct combination of variable1 and variable2

However, there will be multiple dates (date_added) which will have the same combination. I only want to echo out the last combination (according to date). The rows that are echoed out, may have different dates.

Is there any way that I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
SELECT variable1,
       variable2
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM Table1
   ORDER BY date_added DESC) tmp
GROUP BY variable1,
         variable2;
```

Comment: Won't that give me multiple rows which have the same combination of variable1 and variable2?

Comment: I am still getting multiple rows which have the same combination of variable1,variable2

Comment: @user The GROUP BY clause works grouping each line of the tmp table having the same combination of variable1 and variable2. The temp table is created to order the original table so the first line is the one with the most recend date_added.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct(variable1)  variable1, (select distinct (variable2)) as variable2
FROM bmi_users
Order by date_added DESC
```

i hope this will work